# How to set notify-OSD as default in Gnome Classic session?

Tags: notification, gnome-classic, notify-osd

Using Ubuntu 12.04. In Gnome Classic session, notify-OSD has been replaced with this one:

[image: example]

How to set notify-OSD back to default again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should uninstall `notification-daemon`, as `notify-osd` replaces it, however some apps might use `notification-daemon` first if it is available. More info [here on the Ubuntu wiki help page for NotifyOSD](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NotifyOSD)

Comment: It has just worked, although I had to remove the package through the Synaptic. From the Ubuntu Software Center it would remove the fall-back mode as well. Thank you very much.